# Can I extract periodic components using the second smallest eigenvalues of periodicity error?

Tags: matlab, pca, minimize, eigenvalue, periodicity

I want to detect periodic components in EEG channels using Periodic Component Analysis. I describe briefly the procedure because the algorithm is not very well-known.

I **minimize periodicity error function**: `error(τ)= E[s(t+τ) -s(t)] / E[s(t)^2]`, where `τ` is the time lag. If I define matrices `A(τ)`, `C`, `error(τ)=(w'*A(τ)*w)/(w'*C*w) = Rayleigh(A(τ), C, w)`.
So, it's minimum value is the smallest generalized eigenvalue of (`Α(τ)`, `C`), for a certain time lag τ.

I run `piCA` for a range of time lags and usually I detect the periods of the periodic components at the local minimums of the minimized error function(using the smallest generalized eigenvalues). 
`[E,W]=piCA( Xeeg, [minlag maxlag], 'pre', [1 1 1]);`
which gives the tranformation matrix `W` and the matrix `E` of the generalized eigenvalues of all the pairs (`A[τ]`,`C`).

Is it possible to detect the correct periodic components, at the local minimums of NOT the function calculated with the smallest eigenvalues BUT with the second smallest eigenvalues??

See the image below:

[image: Periodicity Error]

The green line is obviously the minimum error function 
for all time lags but **it has no local minimums**!!! So, results can only arise from the blue line function, which is calculated using the second smallest eigenvalues. :/

Comment: Note that the plotted green line has local minimums at it boundaries, i.e. `0` and `0.2`